# 'Submit' button redirects to home page without submitting form (php error, perhaps)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Shortly after setting up my first WordPress website (I've already been to their help forums with no luck), I noticed an error with the "Contact Us" page (http://www.therealironworks.org/contact-us/).  When I first created the page, it was supposed to give errors if the user didn't fill out the form correctly.  Instead, when the user clicks the "submit" button, it redirects to the home page without alerting the user and without submitting information, even if the form is filled out correctly.

I decided to rebuild the website by re-uploading the base files I had from my computer, but when I checked to make sure it was working correctly, the version on my pc was doing the same thing (I'm using MAMP for Windows to emulate a server).  So now I'm wondering if maybe it never did work correctly, in which case it wouldn't be a WordPress problem, but a php coding error on my part.  However, I'm puzzled as the page still loads and does what it should, up to the part where the button is clicked.

The page is in two parts, with the actual meat of the php being in a "content-" template part file.  I'm not sure if I should upload both files here, as they are a bit long, but I could do so if needed.  Any help or even ideas would be appreciated!

```
if ($_POST ['$variable'] ="" || !preg_match... { $error = "string"; } 
if ($_POST ['$variable2'] ="" || !preg_match... { $error .= "string"; } 
if ($_POST [$'variable3'] ="" || !preg_match... { $error .= "string"; } 
if (!$_POST ['$email'] ="" { $error .= "string"; } 
if ($_POST ['$email'] != "" AND !filter_var($_POST['$email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { $error .= "string"; } 
if ($_POST [$'variable4'] ="" { $error .= "string"; } //for the message 
if ($error) { $result = '<div ...> '.$error.' </div>';}
```

Comment: So your `form tag` looks like this... `<form class="form-group" method="post" action="/index.php">`. I don't see any javascript happening at all for error catching and/or ajax submission. So with the action being `/index.php` it'll always submit the form to the index page, regardless of what's filled out.

Comment: So the actual code shows the following for the 'action' parameter: 

`<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">`. 

Any idea what this should be so it points to the appropriate file in the template folder?

Comment: @visevo,
So I noticed an online tutorial about building your own contact form for WordPress (https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-and-why/), and decided to move everything into one file.  Then I changed the php script above to: `<?php the_permalink();?>`, and while that prevents it from returning to the home page, I'm still having problems:
*  returns error only for missing/invalid email (even if email is present)
*  does not validate form even if all information is correct

Due to limited space, I'll post the code in the next comment.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to read that... edit your question to include the code. Try adding it as a code block: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow

Comment: @visevo, done.  Thanks for the help!  I'm also confused because when I did this originally, before I put it in WordPress, it worked just fine.  I just *assumed* that putting it in WordPress would be much simpler than it has turned out to be.

Comment: @visevo,
Actually, I think I got it.  I just changed the `($_POST...)` to `(!$_POST...)` and removed the blank equality (`=""`), and now I've got all my errors showing up as they should.  I'm going to go ahead and edit the live site, and hopefully this will fix the problem there as well.  But if you hadn't pointed out the problem with the `action=` pointer, I never would have figured this out, so thank you very much!

Comment: @visevo,

Well, it turns out my victory dance was a little premature.  Now I continuously get errors even if the fields are filled out properly.  I have tried changing it to "!isset", "empty", and "is_null", all with the same problems (surrounding the variable with parenthesis as required).  I'm still trying, though.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @visevo, it's working properly now.  I changed from `empty` to `!empty` and used AND instead of OR, changing the pre_match from false to true (so it reads, "if variable is not empty AND preg_match is true", input info into php variable, otherwise return error.  Doing this for all variables finally got it working the way it should be.  Problem = solved!

Comment: Glad its working. Since you're using WordPress, I might suggest using a contact form plugin. Many of them have bot-dodging logic built in.